# Angular SSR require json file without extension

Tags: typescript, angular9, tsconfig

I'm starting a new project on Angular SSR and I need to import a library written in JS that inside import a JSON file in this way:

`var json = require('myfile');`

myfile.json exists.

At compile time I obtain the following error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'myfile' in '.... filename'`

Anyone can help me?
There is a way to configure tsconfig.json or angular.json to bypass the error?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

(Not enough rep to comment, so answering instead)

I'm currently having the same issue and as far as i can see, the answer is no. The TypeScript module resolver is currently not capable of doing this, while the NodeJS one can.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24357

Doesn't look like it's going to happen anytime soon.

If you're using WebPack, you can try adding the `.json` extension to your `webpack.config.js`'s `resolve.extensions` array.